# How to open the starting file of an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages app?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, deployment, razor-pages

I have a basic question so apologies in advanced but I have been googling for hours and not been able to find the answer. I made an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages app and deployed it to a folder (which is in a network, it's basically our staging environment) and now need to know how to access the index page in the URL. I followed this doc on how to publish the app into a folder: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs156 (I chose the Self-contained deployment without third-party dependencies option) but now how do I access the index file?

For example if this is the URL: https://testing.com/FolderName

And the app is in the 'FolderName' folder what do I need to follow up next in the URL to open the app? Inside the FolderName folder there is wwwroot folder, appsettings.Development, appsettings, the .exe, a .pdb, and a web.config. So how do I access the app in the web? I also tried copy/pasting the files and navigating to index.cshtml but didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: [Tutorial: Get started with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows), [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Sorry but not helpful, I don't think you read what I posted. I already 'published' it but the issue I'm having is that I can't access the app in the URL. How can I get to index after publishing the app in the network folder?

Answer (score 0):

Razor Pages are not routed based on the file system (like PHP).

You start the Web server (by opening the `exe`) and navigate to the URL where the Web server tells you it's serving the app (in the terminal you should see a line that says "Listening on https://your_url:port...").

> The index should be the first thing you see when you navigate there.

Comment: Thanks. So yes that kinda works but there are two problems. The first one is that it only directs to 'localhost', do you know if there is a file where I can select a URL (server) for it? i.e. if I want the app to be listen in https://testing.com instead of localserver? Also, if I close .exe then the app doesn't work, so basically opening the .exe is the same as launching it from visual studio so it doesn't really work. My objective is to publish the app in my server (which I did) and navigate to it through a network URL so that other people can see it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, the exe is the actual server, called Kestrel, but if you're using other server, like IIS, you can use it as a reverse proxy for Kestrel, so every request done to your server, which I assume has the domain name on it, is forwarded to it. You can read more about the topic here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself well. I don't have a server per se, I have a Network File Share. So I'm trying to publish the razor app into the Network File Share, so others can access it. Is this possible with Razor Pages?

Comment: Well, sadly that's not how servers work. Servers are just PCs running applications that listen to requests, like Kestrel (the exe). So the way to make your application available through your local network is leaving a PC with the Web server (again, the exe) running.  But instead of going to `https://localhost:5001/` you go to `https://the private IP of the PC with the server:5001/` from any device in your network, even your phone. If you would like to deploy it to an actual server, with a domain name, and all, then of course you could use something like Azure or any cloud solution.

Comment: But that's the thing, I'm not using a server. I'm using a Network File Share. Every other time we literally just put app files in the Network File Share and access it through the URL. However this is my first time with Razor Pages and is unbelievable how challenging this is when with other back-ends is super easy. It looks like I'm gonna have to change back-ends and stay away from Razor Pages simply cause I can't access the application via URL in a Network File Share, unreal lol sigh. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Yup, given the context ASP.NET is not really the solution you're looking for, it only can run on a Web server.