# How to access via URL an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages on a Network File Share?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, web-deployment, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages App in a Network File Share so that others can access the application with a URL but I'm having trouble accessing the index file in the URL. How can I do this?

For example, If I were to put a php app called NameApp in the Network File Share with this URL Address: https://Test/ I can access its index.php file with this URL https://Test/NameApp/index.php. Very easy. But with Razor Pages I can't access index.cshtml, I also tried 'publishing' the app into the Network File Share with a .exe but it obviously won't work in the URL either. So, how can I access the index file in a Razor Pages app hosted in a Network File Share? I've spent a lot of time in this reading docs and checking the internet but haven't found an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you're able to access the ASP.NET Core or in fact any server-side technology without a Web Server.

Comment: But isn't php server-side? I can easily access .php files on a Network File Share. Do you know if Node.js is similar to php in that sense? Thinking of maybe changing to node.js since .cshtml of Razor Pages seems like a no go.

Comment: Yeah, I never tested the scenario. But I don't think it will work. If that is possible why we need Apache?

Comment: You have posted the same question twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59958772/how-to-open-the-starting-file-of-an-asp-net-core-razor-pages-app